# on jquery, how to manually define image src into html <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i'm trying to create a page filled with thumbnails, and on click, another div Full(to show the thumbnail image in full screen) will pop out, i will retrieve the src of the thumbnail img and pass into the Full div to display the clicked image.

This is what i have so far, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwhLoyy8/1/

```
<div class="img_section"> 
    <img class="test_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/BjVeUYS.png" alt="logo">
</div>    
<div class="img_section"> 
    <img class="test_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/MA9tr9p.jpg" alt="logo">
</div>
```

for now i am detecting test_img click, and retrieving from js with

```
img = $('<img />', {src    : this.src,
            'class': 'full_image_pic'
        });
```

this.src works fine, but i want to change to detecting on img_section instead of test_img, but i don't know how to retrieve the src, i tried this.test_img.src but it doesn't work.

Reason why i want to detect the div instead of the img directly is because in my real working file i have overlay another  and

while mouseover on the thumbnails, which the detection will not work on the words, since i only make it image-detectable only, so i want to change to detecting the parent div instead.

Another thing is, once i display the full image, how do i display unique Title & description under the full image displayed? Please guide me! Thanks

for Kamal

```
<div class="popUp">
    <div class="fullPic">
        <img class="full_image_pic" src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="logo2">
    <div class="full_image_desc">
         <h3 class="desc">Title</h3>
         <p class="desc">My desc</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle has no JS at all, and the JS you posted above doesn't seem to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the src with jQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
img = $(".test_img").attr('src');
```

and change the src by

```
$(".full_image_pic").attr('src', img);
```

Please also take a look at this [exmaple](http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example32.php).

For changing title and description dynamically, you can add attributes in your original image;

```
<div class="img_section"> 
    <img class="test_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/MA9tr9p.jpg" img-title="some title" img-desc="some description" alt="logo">
</div>
```

Than use the attr to change the info.

```
title = $(".test_img").attr('img-title');
```

and using [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) change the content of title/description

```
$(".full_image_pic .desc").html(title);
```

Comment: works great, i edited it so that it will detect click on parent div and store the children img src with var img = $(this).children(".test_img").attr('src');

Comment: can u also help me answer how i can show the unique title and description along with the different thumbnails that i clicked? For now i can show different images but all of them share a same title and description. I will mark your answer as correct for now since you answered one of my question @kamal

Comment: @Devon How are you displaying title and description?

Comment: i have removed those classes that make my description and title to be under the image, so don't have to worry about it, i just need to know how to dynamically change the title n description based on the image shown

Comment: working very well @devon, so that say if i want to show the author of the work, i can just add another attr like author-img="/path.jpg" and then call it out like this right?

Comment: @devon, you should be able to

Answer (score 1):

You can use class or ID to select an image and change image src

```
$(".image class or #ID").attr("src", "file name");

$(".photo").attr("src", "photo.jpg");

$("#logo").attr("src", "new-logo.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(".test_img").attr("src","abc.jpg");
```